# Rails SSL Google Chrome Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, firefox, google-chrome, ssl

I was away for a week from coding and when I return chrome will not display my rails app with localhost:3000.

The app has SSL on via config.force_ssl = true.

I thought its an app problem, but on firefox it works well.

From the rails server console window, it seems chrome doesn't send the requests right:

```
[2011-10-07 09:21:46] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x00\x00U\x01\x00\x00Q\x03\x00Nמ¿י!┐°J=סאו$íK┬╦φ°S^ºí`ó\x00\x17█\x1E⌐פ╙\x00\x00*\x00 \x00ט\x00ח\x009\x008\x00ה\x005\x00E\x00D\x00f\x003\x002\x00צ\x00A\x00\x04\x00\x05\x00/\x00\x16\x00\x13■ \x00'.
```

while on firefox it is

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-07 09:22:39 +0200
  Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1←[0m
Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (372.0ms)
  ←[1m←[35mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1←[0m
Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 613ms (Views: 610.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

Anyone know how to fix chrome to work?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, but on production ... I am hosting a Rails app on Heroku and I gave it a custom domain. I have setup SSL in my app, in environment/production.rb by setting config.force_ssl = true. 
The problem happens when I try to access my app via Chrome, using the custom domain name I get the scariest screen saying :

"you attempted to reach customdomain.com but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as myapp.herokuapp.com ..."

Any idea on how I can get access to https://customdomain.com without the ugly screen that only Chrome displays? Thanks !!

Comment: I think you need to purchase an SSL certificate for that to be fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to clear your cache first.